# How can I determine if a raspberry pi is powerful enough to run my code?

Tags: python-3.x, raspberry-pi3

Perhaps I posted this with the wrong tags but hopefully someone can help me. I am an engineer finding myself deeper and deeper in automation. Recently I designed an automated system on a raspberry pi. I wrote a pretty simple code which was duplicated to read sensor values from different serial ports simultaneously. I did it this way so I could shut down one script without compromising the others if need be. It runs very well now but I had problems overloading my cpu when I first started (I believe it was because I opened all of the code at once rather than one at a time).

My question is:
How can I determine how much computing power is required by code I have written? How can I spec out a computer to run my code before I start building the robot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The three resources you're likely to be bounded by on any computer are disk, RAM, and CPU (cores). MicroSD cards are cheap, and easily swapped, so the bigger concern is the latter two.

Depending on the language you're writing in, you'll have more or less control over memory usage. Python in particular "saves" the developer by "handling" memory automatically. There are a few good articles on memory management in Python, like [this one](https://realpython.com/python-memory-management/). When running a simple script (e.g. activate these IO pins) on a machine with gigabytes of memory, this is rarely an issue. When running data intensive applications (e.g. do linear algebra on this gigantic array) then you have to worry about how much memory you need to do the computation and whether the interpreter actually frees it when you're done. This is not always easy to calculate but if you [profile](https://pypi.org/project/memory-profiler/) your software on another machine you may be able to estimate it.

CPU utilization is comparatively easy to prepare for. Reserve 1 core for OS and other functions and the rest are available to your software. If you write single threaded code this should be plenty. If you have parallel processing, then either stick to N-1 workers or you'll need to get creative with the software design.

Edit: all of this is with the Raspberry Pi in mind. The Pi is a full computer is a tiny form factor: OS, BIOS, boot time, etc. Many embedded problems can be solved with an Arduino or some other controller which has a different set of considerations.

Comment: Andrew, thank you for such a detailed response! The resources you provided will prove to be very helpful. I have a desktop PC, which is extremely powerful so perhaps I build a raspberry pi profile, make my build there, and then depending on the results move it to a pi? Otherwise, it seems like there is no "you need XXX free space, XXX memory, and XXX GHz" type answer.